# Do I really need kerberos when attempt to npm install mongodb on node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, kerberos

When tring to use

> npm install mongodb

to get my work started to connecting MongoDB server. I get the following information:

> npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency kerberos@~0.0 included
>   from mongod b-core will no longer be automatically installed to
>   fulfill the peerDependency  in npm 3+. Your application will need to
>   depend on it explicitly. / kerberos@0.0.17 install
>   C:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos (node-gyp
>   rebuild) || (exit 0)
>
> C:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos>if not defined
>   npm_config_n ode_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin....\
>   node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild )

My question is DO I need kerberos as a piece of the module so I can use mongo API in node.js correctly? Or kerberos is not an essential while only common API of mongo module without the kerberos functionality?

How to realize "Your application will need to depend on it explicitly."? Use command `npm install mongodb kerberos`? And what if explicitly express that I do **NOT** want to use kerberos?

And another confusion is about these sentances:

> C:\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos>if not defined
>   npm_config_n ode_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin....\
>   node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild )

What does it mean or what is the indication for me?

Any help would be grateful. Thank you very much for reading in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know kerberos is used to diagnose the connection and its one of the essential package of mongodb while installing from npm ,if you dont wan't this package ,create a separate project with your own package.json and app.js with mongodb driver packages(except kerberos),It may solve your problem :)

Link for your reference [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

Comment: Having done the kerberos compiling work through Visual C++ Build Tool. Everything works fine now. Thanks. :)